# How to describe event structures and obtain information?

Tags: kotlin

I want to write a DSL in kotlin that describes events in an event store to generate Java code, JSON examples, schema and documentation based on these descriptions. My current approach is:

A data class `MyEvent` that holds the structure of a event

```
data class MyEvent(val name: String, val version: Int, val content: Map<String, String>)
```

so that I can describe events like

```
val OrderCreated = MyEvent("OrderCreated", 1, mapOf("orderId" to "UUID", "nameOfProduct" to "String(1, 256)", "quantity" to "Integer"))
val OrderCancelled = MyEvent("OrderCancelled", 2, mapOf("orderId" to "UUID", "reason" to "String(100, 1000)"))
val OrderQuestioned = MyEvent("OrderQuestioned", 3, mapOf("orderId" to "UUID", "question" to "String(10, 1000)"))
```

Whereas "String(1, 256)" means it is of type `String` with a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 256 characters.

To iterate over all events to generate everything I want, I need to manually add each event to a list / set

```
fun scanForAllMyEventsInstances(): Set<MyEvent> {
    return hashSetOf(OrderCreated, OrderCancelled, OrderQuestioned)
}
```

This way doesn't feel like the best way.

1. I don't like to be forced to add new events in `scanForAllMyEventsInstances`. I only want to describe a new event at one point.
2. I don't like to create an instance of `MyEvent` for each event. It's all "static" information.

So my question: **How would you do that?** I'd like to have some suggestions.

I use `SpringBoot` at the moment. So don't hesitate to suggest frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I think enum class is your friend here.

```
enum class MyEvent(val eventName: String, val version: Int, val content: Map<String, String>) {
    OrderCreated("OrderCreated", 1, mapOf("orderId" to "UUID", "nameOfProduct" to "String(1, 256)", "quantity" to "Integer")),
    OrderCancelled("OrderCancelled", 2, mapOf("orderId" to "UUID", "reason" to "String(100, 1000)")),
    OrderQuestioned("OrderQuestioned", 3, mapOf("orderId" to "UUID", "question" to "String(10, 1000)"))
}
```

And you can iterate over instances

```
MyEvent.values().forEach { println(it.eventName) }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

With the approach of enum classes, I added an interface so that I can organize plenty of (different) events

```
interface MyEvent2 {
    val eventName: String
    val version: Int
    val content: Map<String, String>
}

enum class MyOrderEvents : MyEvent2 {

    OrderCreated {
        override val eventName = "OrderCreated"
        override val version = 1
        override val content = mapOf("orderId" to "UUID", "nameOfProduct" to "String(1, 256)", "quantity" to "Integer")
    },

    OrderCancelled {
        override val eventName = "OrderCancelled"
        override val version = 2
        override val content = mapOf("orderId" to "UUID", "reason" to "String(100, 1000)")
    },

    OrderQuestioned {
        override val eventName = "OrderQuestioned"
        override val version = 3
        override val content = mapOf("orderId" to "UUID", "question" to "String(10, 1000)")
    }

}

enum class MyUserEvents : MyEvent2 {

    UserCreated {
        override val eventName = "UserCreated"
        override val version = 1
        override val content = mapOf("userId" to "UUID", "name" to "String(1, 256)")
    },

    UserDeleted {
        override val eventName = "UserDeleted"
        override val version = 2
        override val content = mapOf("userId" to "UUID")
    },

    UserChanged {
        override val eventName = "UserChanged"
        override val version = 3
        override val content = mapOf("userId" to "UUID", "newName" to "String(1, 256)")
    }

}
```

I still need to add each enum class to a list/set.

```
fun scanForAllMyEventsInstances(): Set<MyEvent2> {
    val allEvents = HashSet<MyEvent2>()
    allEvents.addAll(MyOrderEvents.values())
    allEvents.addAll(MyUserEvents.values())
    return allEvents
}

fun main() {
    scanForAllMyEventsInstances().forEach{e -> println(e.eventName)}
}
```

But only once per class. Each new event within that class is automatically recognized. That's fine for me.

remark: The `val name` should not be used when using an enum class because in enum classes the value `name` is already defined. That's why in `MyEvent2` it's called `eventName`. Maybe I even can skip `name` / `eventName` because it's 1:1 to the enum name.

I will have a try with this.

PS: It's still not a nice DSL, I think. But optimizing this, I will do in a future task.